# (Proof verification). If for every sequence $x_n \to \infty$ implies $f(x_n) \to L$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

We are given that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$, and suppose there exists some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a, \infty) \subseteq A$.

I wish to prove that if for every sequence $(x_n) \subseteq A \cap (a, \infty)$ such that $x_n \to \infty$, the sequence $f(x_n) \to L$, then we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$.

To prove this, I'm trying to use a contrapositive argument.

Assuming $\lim_{x \to \infty} f \not= L$, this means there is some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for all $k > a$, there exists $x > k$ such that $|f(x) -L | \ge \epsilon_0$. (Here $k \in \mathbb{N}$.)

Now, given any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists some $k \ge \alpha$ and therefore some $x > k$.

For each $n$, we choose some $k(n) \ge \alpha$ such that $x_n > k(n) \ge \alpha$. This means $x_n \to \infty$, but $|f(x_n) - L | \ge \epsilon_0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This means $f(x_n) \to L$ is not true.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, well done.

Comment: You have to bind the variable $n$. It is without context/meaning as it is now. Same goes for the sequence in the title.

Comment: I think there is some confusion with the notation. The notation $f(x_n)\to L$ as $x_n\to\infty$ *just means* $\lim_{x_n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$, in which case there is nothing to prove. I think you mean to distinguish $f(\color{red}{x_n})$ from $f(\color{blue}{x})$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic There was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @polynomial_donut I don't think I understand what you mean. Would you mind writing down what you have in mind exactly?

Comment: **In the title:** Does the implication hold for *some* sequence or for *any* sequence? **In the text body:** $(x_n)_n \subset A \cap (a,\,\infty)$, but what does that mean? Do you actually mean to state that there is (exists) some nat. number $N$, such that this holds true for all $n\geq N$ ? You have to state that.

Comment: Oh never mind the last part... it's a notation I like to forget.

Comment: Your problem still is kind of scrambled. Edit your post to make it clear (instead of posting such information in the comment ection).

Comment: @polynomial_donut, I'm sorry. I will do that.

Comment: @polynomial_donut I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: Much better :) I'd advise you to clearly write down for yourself what $lim_n(x_n) = \infty$ means/how it is defined in your context, *and* how you defined the meaning of $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ in general. There are multiple ways to define this with subtle differences. If you are clear about the definitions, I'm sure will figure it out. Right now, it seems like you are switching back and forth between different definitions (and I'm not entirely sure what definition you have been taught). Good luck!